# Unable to run conda in Mac OS after installing Anaconda

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda

After installing Anaconda, I try to validate the install, and when I run conda in bash, I get a 'command not found' error.

I'm running macOS Sierra and trying to installing Anaconda for Python 2.7.

Comment: Did you activate the root environment? `source ~/anaconda/bin/activate root`?

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda places it's binaries in it's own install directory. [As mentioned in the Anaconda documentation](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/faq#what-is-the-default-path-for-installing-anaconda) the defaults for these are as follows:

> - Windows 10: `C:\Users\<your-username>\Anaconda3\`
> - macOS: `/Users/<your-username>/anaconda3`
> - Linux: `/home/<your-username>/anaconda3`

When installing Anaconda [it should prompt you](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/faq#should-i-add-anaconda-to-the-macos-or-linux-path):

> Do you wish the installer to prepend the Anaconda<2 or 3>install
>   location to PATH in your /home//.bashrc?

If you choose not to do this then the path to the Anaconda binaries will not be added to your `PATH` environment variable in your shell. Therefor you will either need to call the activate script using the full path to your install directory (in macOS), like:

```
/Users/<your-username>/anaconda3/bin/activate root
```

Alternatively, you should manually add the Anaconda binary path to your PATH environment file in your `~/.bashrc` file. Instructions on how do do this can be found in the Anaconda documentation, here: [Should I add Anaconda to the macOS or Linux PATH?](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/faq#should-i-add-anaconda-to-the-macos-or-linux-path)

Comment: I reran the install, it didn't prompt me . I ended up updating $PATH manually.